# How do I come up with a formula to calculate the possible combinations of this set?

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say I have the letters a, a, a, b, c, d. I can only arrange them in pairs of 2. If I use up a letter, I cannot use it again. Order doesn't matter.

So the possible sets of pairs I can get are:

(a,a)(a,b)(c,d)

(a,b)(a,c)(a,d)

(a,c)(a,a)(b,d)

(a,d)(a,a)(b,c)

How do I come up with a way to calculate that there would be 4 possiblities? I tried the combination and permutation calculators on the internet but they didn't work because they would either give me 15 probabilities or 30 probababilities.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider the cases for whether there is a pair with two $a$'s or not. Then clearly there is only $1$ case where no pair has two $a$'s If a pair does have two $a$'s then another pair must have exactly one and then there are only $3$ ways to arrange the remaining letters. Sometimes there are too many conditions and you must use a combination of techniques (or a more general result than what you currently know).

Comment: Is there a formula that would also be able to calculate this?